# Does WP suppresses .htaccess if permalinks are disabled?

Tags: htaccess, apache

I would like to use a .htaccess file, but still use the default link structure of WP.
I didn't turn on permalinks, but did create my own .htaccess file.

To my surprise, the file is being completely ignored by WP (and the server).

I thought that .htaccess takes effect right on apache and before PHP runs, so how can it be that the file is ignored?

I need this to redirect some URLs from the old website to the new one to prevent SEO juice loss (SEO's person definition :).

Any idea how to "enable" the .htaccess functionality without enabling permalinks?
Currently what ever I do is ignored, even no 500 error for just giberishing the file...
Thanks!

Comment: Are you sure that your server supports it?

Comment: Hi and thanks for the comment. Yes, i am sure. After permalinks are enabled all is working fine, including my custom rules...

Comment: @Yanipan you might want to flag this question to close it as you've 'solved' your problem then

Comment: @Damien - That's the thing :) I don't want permalinks and have no clue how the .htaccess is overridden ...